# Async operations and UI update

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await, caliburn.micro

In a wpf application made of caliburn micro and telerik controls I've different screens that load data from a remote service then show data in a gridview /fills comboboxes.
I'm using a sync/await operators to make the load retrieval operations but I'm almost certain it has some bottleneck.
Doing await I have the main UI thread to wait syncronization with the worker thread... Consider this sample

```
Public class MyViewModel:Screen
{
  [omiss]

Public bool IsBusy {get;set;}  
 Public list<Foo> DropDownItems1 {get;set;}
Public  list<Foo2> DropDownItems2 {get;set;}

  Public async Void Load()
  {
    IsBusy =true;
     DropDownItems1 = await repository.LoadStates();
     DropDownItems2 = await repository.LoadInstitutes();
     IsBusy = false;
  }

}
```

In that case I've first task loaded then second with no parallelism...how can I optimize this?
About my IsBusy property that's bound via convention to a busy indicator how can it be properly set ?
thanks

Update #1:

I'n my real code I do

```
public async Task InitCacheDataTables()
    {
        var taskPortolio = GetPortfolio();
        var taskInstitutes = GetInstitutes();
        var taskStatus = GetStatus();
        var taskCounterparts = GetCounterparts();
        var taskCrosses = GetCrosses();
        var taskCurrencies = GetCurrencies();
        var taskSigns = GetSigns();

        await TaskEx.WhenAll(new[] { taskPortolio, taskInstitutes, taskStatus, taskCounterparts, taskCrosses, taskCurrencies, taskSigns });
    }
```

where Tasks are like

```
 private async Task GetPortfolio()
    {
        try
        {
            dynamicContainer.SetValue(UserContainerKeyHelper.Portfolios, await commonRepository.GetPortfoliosAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorHandler.HandleErrorAsync(ex);
        }
    }
    private async Task GetInstitutes()
    {
        try
        {
            dynamicContainer.SetValue(UserContainerKeyHelper.Institutes, await commonRepository.GetInstitutesAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorHandler.HandleErrorAsync(ex);
        }
    }
```

While debugging I've seen that all the methods are executed on the MainThread...wasn't supposed to be on workerthread?

Comment: If your desired optimization would be running two parallel background threads instead of just one?, you can use the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll()` method. The `IsBusy` assignment looks okay, but assuming your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you'd need something like an `onPropertyChanged("IsBusy")` each time when you set the property content in order to notify the XAML "View"

Comment: OT: put the logic inside try...finaly block, so you always set IsBusy to false, event if exception occurs: `IsBusy=True; try{....} finally {IsBusy=False;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In that case I've first task loaded then second with no parallelism...how can I optimize this?

You want concurrency, not parallelism. Instead of awaiting each task sequentially, you can await on them both using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task LoadAsync()
{
     IsBusy = true;

     var firstDropDownItemsTask = repository.LoadStates();
     var secondDropDownItemsTask = repository.LoadInstitutes();

     await Task.WhenAll(DropDownItems1Task, DropDownItems2Task);

     DropDownItems1 = firstDropDownItemsTask.Result;
     DropDownItems2 = secondDropDownItemsTask.Result;

     IsBusy = false;
}
```

> IsBusy property that's bound via convention to a busy indicator how can it be properly set ?

Usually, items bound via convention need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to update the xaml binding that a value has been updated.

Comment: Yes it's bound via Caliburn Micro convention and yes it implements INotiftyPropertyChanged... it's best to have try catch inside the repo? what happens if LoadStates fails with Task.WhenAll?

Comment: That depends on your design decisions. If you handle exceptions at the repo level, then do that. If you handle exceptions in your business layer, you'll need to wrap `LoadAsync` in a try-catch and handle it there.

Comment: but if something fails in the Task[] passed to when all it stops the other threads right? it doesn't trow an aggreagate exception as far I've seen

Comment: @advapi There are no extra threads in your repo queries. I'd advise you to [read the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the main post since I've noticed that all goes on UI Thread